# np.array separates my matrix into single rows

Tags: arrays, struct, integer, pcap, unpack

I'm trying to read a pcap file with python, using the function sniff from the scapy library and the function 'struct.unpack' to read the integers and the bytes of this file.
I have no problem in this, and from the struct.unpack I extract every field I want. So after the struct.unpack I will write in my code things like this: 'Msg_Kind = int (packet[1])'. The problem I have is when I have to do my post-processing. Infact, If I want to create a vector or a matrix with the fields I got, using np.array([Msg_Kind]) (for example), comes out a matrix of all separated rows with dimension (1,). Actually the field is 1*10.

[image]

I also try to construct the matrix without np.array but it's the same.
How can I do to merge these rows?